# Display function of Circular Linked List Debugging

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, circular-list

I have tried to implement Circular Linked List with features like insertion, deletion at position, then repeated insertion or deletion based on changing position. However there is a case when initially the list is not yet created and I want to insert at position 1. My program should allow this and should give invalid position for other positions for the mentioned case. However whenever I am trying to do this it is giving me segmentation fault during display in the while loop. Please help. My code is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node node;

node *head;
int count=0;



void insert(int d,int pos)
{
    if((pos==(count+1))||(head==NULL))
    {
        addnode(d);
    }
    else
    {
        if(pos==1)
        {
            node *newnode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
            newnode->data = d;
            newnode->next = head;
            head = newnode;
            tail->next = newnode;
        }
        else
        {
            int a = 1;
            node *temp = head;
            while(a!=(pos-1))
            {
                temp = temp->next;
                a++;
            }
            node *newnode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
            newnode->data = d;
            newnode->next = temp->next;
            temp->next = newnode;
        }
        count++;
    }
}

void display()
{
    node *temp = head;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        printf("Empty List \n");
        return;
    }
    while(temp->next != head)       
    {
        printf("%d ",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("%d %d\n",temp->data,temp->next->data);
}
```

Comment: Please reduce the code to a [mre]. That is, remove all code not strictly needed to reproduce the problem. For example, remove all the user input code and just hard code test values. Similarly remove the menu system and just hard code the minimum function call sequence needed to reproduce the problem. And so on.

Comment: Ok @kaylum let me try.

Comment: @kaylum I have tried it but same problem.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. A requirement of Stack Overflow questions is that they must show a **minimal** example of the code. So you need to update the question with all unnecessary code removed. Please see [ask] and [mre] for more info on what is expected and how to create  the minimal example.

Comment: Oh ok thanks. I am new to stack overflow. I will keep it in mind next time. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the list is empty, i.e. `head` is NULL, your `addnode` doesn't create a circular list.

Your code will set `newnode->next` to NULL (because `head` is NULL) but what you want is `newnode->next = newnode` to get a circular list.

So inside `addnode` you need:

```
    ...
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head = newnode;
        tail = newnode;
        newnode->next = newnode;
    }
    ...
```

Alternatively you can move the line `newnode->next = head;` to be **after** the `if-else` clause.